# C++ Nested data structure utilizing struct

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, nested

So I'm trying to come up with a simple data structure that would have shop chains, their shop locations and the products & their prices.

The solution I wanted to try for it was following, but because I forgot that C++ does not support dynamic naming it did not work. Can I somehow alter this logic into something that C++ can handle?

Example vector containing the data I want to save to my data structure would be something like

```
{"chain_nameX", "location_nameX", "product_nameX", product_priceX}
```

where the first 3 entries would be strings and the last one would be either an int or a string (if the product was out of stock it would not have a price value, but a string).

I *have* to use this struct for my data structure, but because of not being able to use dynamic naming I'm a little bit lost as to what would be a natural solution.

```
struct Product {
    string productname;
    double price;
};
```

This is the struct I created to contain a shop location and the product data from above struct in a vector, but I wanted to utilize dynamic naming so I'm not sure if this is actually a good way to approach it

```
struct Shop {
    string shop_location;
    vector <Product> shop_locations;
};
```

So, I wanted to start storing the data by using logic like this:

```
    Shop word_segments[1];
```

but because dynamic naming is not actually a thing in C++, it will not work. Are there any smooth solutions to formulating data structures like this?

Also, I'm *mandated* to use the pre-determined struct `Product`, but isn't the Product as a struct kind of redundant? If I call it by the shop location, then the limit would be only one product and if I call it by the product name, then why does it contain a `productname` string within it?

Edit:
If I just name the struct data structures as set names and save them to vectors/other data structures, will they remain unchanged when I rename their elements for other parts of the data structures or will their value change globally? (let me know if this sounds too confusing and I'll put up an example as to what I mean)

Edit2: Did according to suggestion

```
Product product;
    product.productname = word_segments[2];
    product.price = price;

    Shop shop;
    shop.products.push_back(product);
    shop.shop_location = word_segments[1];

    ShopChain shopchain;
    shopchain.name = word_segments[0];
    shopchain.shops.push_back(shop);

    chains[word_segments[0]].push_back(shopchain);

    all_possible_products.push_back(word_segments[2]);
    chain_names.push_back(word_segments[0]);
```

"chains" is defined as `map<string, vector<ShopChain>> chains;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to understand what you'd need dynamic naming for. You seem to be missing some basic knowledge about data structures, so let me show you one approach:

On the top level, we will have this:

```
std::vector<ShopChain> shop_chains;
```

where `ShopChain` is:

```
struct ShopChain {
     std::string name;              // shop chain has-a name
     std::vector<Shop> shops;       // and shops
     std::vector<Product> products; // and products (common for all shops)
};
```

where `Product` is defined in your question and `Shop` is:

```
struct Shop {
    std::string location; // shop has-a location
};
```

`vector <Product> shop_locations;` as a member was making very little sense to me.

---

You might need to move `products` under `Shop`, if you think their merchandise will not always be the same. Maybe you'd also not want to store duplicates of `Product`, so you'd need to store them in a separate data structure and only keep references to them.

Comment: What I'm having trouble with is being able to smoothly create new data structures for new shop chains, since the shop chains, their shops nor the products in the individual shops are not pre-determined.

In Python I would be able to dynamically name and call the data structure with `Shop word_segments[1] = somestring;` , but that doesn't do much good in C++

Comment: @Grak I think you don't need new data structures, you just need to fill the data structure with data. Is that the problem?

Comment: To be honest I'm having a hard time at grasping the logic with the data structures built with `struct`. If I'm going to have numerous chains & shops & products for it. I think I'm going to fiddle around a bit to see if I can grasp how they work better

Comment: @Grak Could you show me the exact python syntax? Are you looking for a dictionary, i.e. `std::map`?

Comment: "conflicting declaration 'main()::Product word_segments [2]' "

Though I was able to get error free with this code, but what I'm not sure about is whether or not I can make do with this within a for-function, or would it screw up the earlier elements or not accept new elements (Adding it to the original question because of visibility) Also: the two last vectors that I'm pushing back on are for later use when I want to iterate. Not sure if I need them though

Comment: @Grak This is how you declare a vector: `std::vector<ShopChain> shop_chains;`, this is how you append an element (at index `0`, of course): `shop_chains.push_back(chain);` and you append another element at subsequent index the same way. You can also use the `std::vector`s constructor overload taking `std::initializer_list` - [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Because `Shop word_segments[1]` means a declaration of an **array of one** vector, `Shop word_segments[2]` is an **array of two** vectors. They can't have the same name...